# Java regex for number range

Tags: java, regex, numbers, range

Hi I required a Java regular expression to match ANY of the following:

> 1,2,3 W   ie: 1W or 2W or 3W etc, etc 
>  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
>   M 
>  1,2 Y

I have tried using the following but it does not work correctly

```
[0-2]{1}W|[1-12]{2}M|[1-2]{1}Y
```

Thanks

Comment: `[..]` is a character class. It doesn't do what you think it does and it *doesn't care* the the contents happen to be numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([1-3]W|[1-9]M|1[0-2]M|[12]Y)$
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5B1-3%5DW%7C%5B1-9%5DM%7C1%5B0-2%5DM%7C%5B12%5DY%29%24&input=These%20should%20match%0A1W%0A2W%0A3W%0A1M%0A2M%0A3M%0A4M%0A5M%0A6M%0A7M%0A8M%0A9M%0A10M%0A11M%0A12M%0A1Y%0A2Y%0A%0AThese%20should%20not%20match%0A1%0A4W%0A13M%0A3Y%0AW)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^([1-3]W|(1[0-2]|[1-9])M|[12]Y)$
```

[Here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28%5B1-3%5DW%7C%281%5B0-2%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%29M%7C%5B12%5DY%29%24) is the explanation:

```
  ^         --> the beginning of the string
  (         --> group and capture to \1:
    [1-3]   --> any character of: '1' to '3'
    W       --> 'W'
    |       --> OR
    (       --> group and capture to \2:
      1     --> '1'
      [0-2] -->any character of: '0' to '2'
    |       --> OR
      [1-9] --> any character of: '1' to '9'
    )       --> end of \2
    M       --> 'M'
   |        --> OR
    [12]    --> any character of: '1', '2'
    Y       --> 'Y'
  )         --> end of \1
  $         --> before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that experienced in regex but,
try seperate the three opportunities. 
For example:

([0-3]W)|((1[0-2])|([1-9])M)|([12]J)

I dont see that you want to find the word at the beginning of a line,
so there is no need for ^ and $

Tested with [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)